# Flashing pixels on Ubuntu 18.04 installed alongside Windows 8

Tags: nvidia, 18.04, intel-graphics, screen

I installed ubuntu 18.04 on my windows 8 computer (Toshiba qosmio x70-a), the Ubuntu Live  desktop was having flashing pixel lines:

[image: like this],

I didn't give it importance and installed it anyways, I suspected that it was the graphics card driver (the computer has an NVidia GeForce GTX 770M & Intel HD Graphics 4600), I tried using the software and update to install the drivers for the nvidia graphics card but it didn't seem to solve the problem and my Ubuntu screen is still having flashing lines, and I started to think, that maybe its not the nvidia drivers but the intel drivers, which controls the display (according to my windows dxdiag) , so I am looking for a solution for it, since I need to run gazebo and ros smoothly.

Answer (score 0):

Installed ubuntu 16.04, ubuntu live disk didnt't have issues, but when I rebooted the machine, happened the same thing,  so I started ubuntu 16.04 with linux 4.13.0-36 kernel instead of the 0- 45and it works fine... Guess it was not the graphics cards but the kernel. If someone knows why, please, help us  writing the answer below.